# R How to Get the Average of One Variable based on Ranges of Another Variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

If I have a series of observations with two variables X and Y, how can I get the average value of Y based on ranges of variable X?

So for example, with some data like:

`df = data.frame(x=runif(50,1,100),y=runif(50,300,700))`

How could I get the answer to "When X is 1-10 the average of y 332.4, when X is 11-20 the average of y is 632.3, etc...."

Comment: Public service announcement.  Stand well clear.  We anticipate an avalanche of answers using `tapply`, `ddply` and `aggregate`

Comment: @Andrie, when I saw 3 answers in the space of 22 seconds while typing mine (which was basically yours, except I called the new variable `xgroup`), I didn't even bother finishing typing. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cut your x using `cut` and then use `ddply` in package `plyr`:

```
> df$xrange <- cut(df$x, breaks=seq(0, 100, 10))

library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(xrange), summarize, mean_y=mean(y))
     xrange   mean_y
1    (0,10] 490.7571
2   (10,20] 462.6347
3   (20,30] 507.5614
4   (30,40] 482.6004
5   (40,50] 510.3081
6   (50,60] 480.7927
7   (60,70] 507.8944
8   (70,80] 458.4668
9   (80,90] 501.9672
10 (90,100] 493.4844
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `cut` to form groups and `tapply` to summarise over them.

```
df$grp <- cut(df$x, seq(0, 100, 10))
with(df, tapply(y, grp, mean))
```

If you are a `plyr` fan you may prefer

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(grp), summarise, m = mean(y))
```

For completeness, the `aggregate` version is

```
aggregate(y ~ grp, df, mean)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `cut()` to create a factor from the `x` variable, specifying breaks every ten units.  Given that factor, you can then use `by()` or `aggregate()` or ... to summarise the data frame, or rather just column `y`:

```
R> set.seed(42); DF <- data.frame(x=runif(50,1,100), y=rnorm(50,30,70))
R> summary(DF)
       x               y         
 Min.   : 1.39   Min.   :-179.5  
 1st Qu.:40.66   1st Qu.: -19.4  
 Median :64.45   Median :  39.6  
 Mean   :60.29   Mean   :  25.9  
 3rd Qu.:90.10   3rd Qu.:  74.7  
 Max.   :98.90   Max.   : 140.3  
R> DF$cx <- cut(DF$x, breaks=seq(0,100,by=10))
R> ?by
R> by(DF, DF$cx, FUN=function(z) mean(z$y))
DF$cx: (0,10]
[1] 67.8747
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (10,20]
[1] 52.9104
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (20,30]
[1] -53.8961
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (30,40]
[1] 44.1992
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (40,50]
[1] 21.7404
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (50,60]
[1] 16.2122
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (60,70]
[1] -27.0338
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (70,80]
[1] 42.283
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (80,90]
[1] 40.8042
--------------------------------------------- 
DF$cx: (90,100]
[1] 38.8917
R>
```

Or using `ddply()`:

```
R> library(plyr)
R> ddply(DF, .(cx), function(z) mean(z$y))
         cx       V1
1    (0,10]  67.8747
2   (10,20]  52.9104
3   (20,30] -53.8961
4   (30,40]  44.1992
5   (40,50]  21.7404
6   (50,60]  16.2122
7   (60,70] -27.0338
8   (70,80]  42.2830
9   (80,90]  40.8042
10 (90,100]  38.8917
R>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is causing your answers to be too narrow. You ought to be thinking of regression methods to summarize the joint relationships of continuous variables. Plotting with scatterplots and fitting regression splines is going to do less violence to the underlying relationships than the piecewise analysis that you specified.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `data.table` solution

```
require(data.table)
data.table(df)[,list(mean_y = mean(y)), by = 'cut(x, seq(0, 100, 10))']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tapply` with `pretty` to make the breakpoints for `cut`:

```
 tapply(df$y,cut(df$x,pretty(range(df$x),high.u.bias=0.1)),mean)
  (0,10]  (10,20]  (20,30]  (30,40]  (40,50]  (50,60]  (60,70]  (70,80] 
496.9840 510.4164 502.4092 492.5806 493.3364 549.5207 507.4511 472.3391 
 (80,90] (90,100] 
479.8795 482.6728
```

`aggregate` can also be used:

```
aggregate(df$y,list(cut(df$x,pretty(range(df$x),high.u.bias=0.1))),FUN=mean)
    Group.1        x
1    (0,10] 496.9840
2   (10,20] 510.4164
3   (20,30] 502.4092
4   (30,40] 492.5806
5   (40,50] 493.3364
6   (50,60] 549.5207
7   (60,70] 507.4511
8   (70,80] 472.3391
9   (80,90] 479.8795
10 (90,100] 482.6728
```